# Docker push "Missing image name"-error when pushing to GCP Artifact Registry from Github Actions

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-artifact-registry

I am running the [google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun) Action on Github, which **fails when trying to push a docker image to Artifact Registry**.

1. I authenticate through an identity pool
2. The docker image builds successfully
3. However, pushing the image to `Google Artifact Registry` fails with `name invalid: Missing image name. Pushes should be of the form docker push HOST-NAME/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE`

**Github action YML**

```
# Authenticate Docker to Google Cloud Artifact Registry
  - name: Docker Auth
    id: docker-auth
    uses: 'docker/login-action@v1'
    with:
      username: 'oauth2accesstoken'
      password: '${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token }}'
      registry: '${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev'

  - name: Build and Push Container
    run: |-
      docker build -t "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}" .
      docker push "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}"
```

**Log output**

```
Successfully built 2edd636b95c7
Successfully tagged us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/[my-project]/github-actions:ecb28fdf92addae09fe6bd9e86033027b2850de3
The push refers to repository [us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/[my-project]/github-actions]
8189f048f482: Retrying in 5 seconds
... multiple retries ...
name invalid: Missing image name. Pushes should be of the form docker push HOST-NAME/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I do have Artifact Registry enabled, and created repository with the path `us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/[my-project]/github-actions`

The IAM role has following permissions

- Artifact Registry Administrator
- Cloud Run Admin
- Service Account User

I am out of ideas why to the authenticated docker it appears that the registry doesn't exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out, the above notation is only specifying `HOST-NAME/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY:tag` but not `/IMAGE`

Replacing all occurrences by e.g. `${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}/website:${{ github.sha }}` will use  /`website` as the actual image name within the repository.

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same issue.

Adding to the answer above, instead of hardcoding "/website", I changed the original script to add the name as a variable:

```
docker build -t "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}" ./
docker push "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue. When creating a repository in Artifact Registry, the "repository" will contain many different images instead of being a repository for a single image with different tags.

If you want to match the naming scheme to your GitHub repository, you can use the following as your Docker image name:

```
docker build -t "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}" .
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).